# Viewport dimensions not matching "visible part of screen"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, viewport

I am trying to create a tooltip component in react such that when it is close to the side of the screen, it will align itself with the child. The issue that I am facing is that when I try to get the window size (window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight) or the position of the component using "getBoundingClientRect", they are giving me the width/height and position of the component with respect to what looks like the div instead of the view port (see attached picture)[image: sizeOfContainer][image: innerWidth and innerHeight being printed in console][image: Actual viewport height/width]

"getBoundingClientRect" is giving me the position relative to the size of the middle section. My tooltip is supposed to display when hovering over "Hover here to see tooltip". Currently it is saying that both top and left are 8px. In the console I am outputing the results of innerHeight, innerWidth and getBoundingClientRect of the component.

This is the code that I am using for the position

```
useEffect(() => {
   const { innerWidth, innerHeight } = window;
   const {
     top,
     bottom,
     right,
     left,
     width
   } = reference.current.getBoundingClientRect();
   if (position !== 'left' && position !== 'right') {
     if (left <= 45 && dataLength > width) {
       setLeftOffset(calculateOffset(width, 'left'));
     }

     if (top <= 45) {
       setPosition('bottom');
     }

     if (right >= innerWidth - 45 && dataLength > width) {
       setLeftOffset(-calculateOffset(width, 'right'));
     }

     if (bottom >= innerHeight - 45) {
       setPosition('top');
     }
   }

   // If left or right, need an extra 5px offset
   if (position === 'left') setLeftOffset(5);

   if (position === 'right') setLeftOffset(-5);
 }, [window]);
```

Am I just not understanding viewport correctly? What can I do to get the actual position of the component relative to the screen and the actual size of the viewable content? Any help would be greatly appreciated!